# How to "Mark instance" in Eclipse Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm looking for the equivalent functionality of IntelliJ IDEA ["Mark instance"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/debugger-basics.html#d165252e206) in Eclipse Debug.

I've searched extensively also in documentation, but I think this feature is not existing in Eclipse Debugger. I can count instances, I can find references, but appears there is no way in the "Variables" window to mark a specific instance with ID with a visual label for convenience while debugging. Before giving up, I preferred to ask also this audience.

## Practical example

Assuming the following (minimal, easy, synthetic) example code:

```
    Object obj1 = "Hello World";
    Object obj2 = 12345L;

    Object result;
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        result = obj1;
    } else {
        result = obj2;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

if I put a breakpoint on the System.out line, I'd like to know if the instance of variable `result` is the same instance of variable `obj1`.

#### Using IntelliJ IDEA

This can be done by "Mark instance" on `obj1` :

[image: by "Mark instance" on <code>obj1</code>]

As you can notice a visual label is applied to all the variable sharing the same instance reference, in this case also `result`:

[image: a visual label is applied to all the variable sharing the same instance reference]

#### Using Eclipse Debug

Appears there is now way to have the Eclipse Debugger visual mark instance ID=16 in order to recognize which other variables are sharing the same instance as of `obj1`.

[image: Eclipse Debugger example]

(Of course this is a simplified example and it's visually easy to detect it even without this feature, but in a real case it would be a very helpful way to understand where an instance is shared across "Variables" and a great additional tool for debugging)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 4.22 now has a feature for "marking a specific instance with ID with a visual label for convenience while debugging"!
(End of 2021, almost 5 years after the OP)

> ### [Label Objects during debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/jdt.php#label-objects)
>
> During debugging a Java application, often we have to deal with lot's of object instances, and it's not always easy to distinguish between them.
>
> That's why the experience is improved, with the ability to set a label on individual objects.
>
> [image: Menu item -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/label-object-menu.png]
>
> After setting a label, everywhere the object appears it is displayed with a distinctive color and with the label:
>
> [image: Objects with Label -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/label-object-result.png]

Comment: Wow thank you @VonC I never expected an answer on this question *5 years* later, but thank you, I just verified with eclipseIDE 2021-12 (4.22.0) and indeed include this capability!

Comment: @tarilabs No problem, thank you for the feedback.